# Domain restriction to sparse vectors makes a non-injective linear map injective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map. If $m<n$, then $A$ is not injective. Now let $S_k$ be the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have at most $k$ non-zero entries. Then $A:S_k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is injective if and only if every subset of up to $2k$ columns of $A$ is linearly independent.

I understand the idea that a domain restricition can lead to a given linear map / matrix $A$ becoming injective. What I don't understand is why the last statement holds true though. I tried to prove it but failed so far.

I'm already confused at the fact that $S_k$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it's not closed under vector addition. E.g. let $n=3$ and $k=1$. Then $v=(1,0,0)^\mathrm{T}\in S_1$ and $w=(0,1,0)^\mathrm{T}\in S_1$ but $v+w=(1,1,0)^\mathrm{T}\notin S_1$. So how do I go about proving that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is not injective on $S_k$, then $Av = Aw$ for some $v,w \in S_k$. Note that $v-w \in S_{2k}$ so the equation $A(v-w) = 0$ gives a linear dependence between (at most) $2k$ columns of $A$.

Conversely, if there is a linear dependence between (at most) $2k$ columns of $A$ we can write this dependence as an equation $A x = 0$ with $x \in S_{2k}$ and it is clear that we can find $v,w \in S_k$ with $x = v - w$. Then $A v = A w$ and $A$ is not injective on $S_k$.

Comment: Of course. I didn't consider that $v,w\in S_k$ implies $v\pm w\in S_{2k}$. Neat!

Comment: Maybe an addendum to my question: What range can we choose $k$ in for this to hold? There are at most $\min(m,n)=m$ independent columns in $A$, so $2k\leq m$?

Comment: The statement that $A$ is injective on $S_k$ if and only if every $2k$ columns of $A$ are linear independent holds for every $k \geq 0$ but of course we only get something useful out of it for the bound you are suggesting.